# How can I have tick marks in Core Plot with custom labels?

Tags: iphone, core-plot

For my app's graph (line plots) it does not make sense to format the axis labels to tenths. It did not look like there was a way to change this without providing custom labels.

I was able to add custom axis labels based on the sample code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993925/how-do-i-add-labels-to-cpbarplot-barplots/2001280#2001280), but the labels do not have tick marks.

Is this an issue (I didn't see anything [here](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list)) or am I missing something?

Comment: Hello,
How did you manage to get some ticks with your custom labels ? Same problem here, custom labels ok but no ticks.
Thanks, Luc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want numeric labels with a format different than the default, create an `NSNumberFormatter` object, set it to whatever format you need, and assign it to the `labelFormatter` property on the axis.

Check out the `CPTimeFormatter` class if you need to format the labels as dates and/or times.

Answer (score 4):

Derive a class from `NSNumberFormatter` (e.g. `MyFormatter`) and override `stringForObjectValue:`

```
- (NSString *)stringForObjectValue:(NSDecimalNumber *)coordinateValue {
    return @"MyLabel";
}
```

Then set the labelFormatter property of your axis to an instance of `MyFormatter`, e.g.:

```
MyFormatter *formatter = [[MyFormatter alloc] init];
x.labelFormatter = formatter;
[formatter release];
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me!

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; 
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];  
y.labelFormatter = formatter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also swizzle the method in category like this:

```
#import "NSNumberFormatter+BigNumber.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static Method origStringFromNumberMethod = nil;

@implementation NSNumberFormatter (BigNumber)

-(NSString *)stringFromBigNumber:(NSNumber*)number{
    int result = 0;
    int level = 1;
    NSString *format = @"";
    if([number integerValue] >= 1000000000) {
        level = 1000000000;
        format = @"b";
    }
    if([number integerValue] >= 1000000) {
        level = 1000000;
        format = @"m";
    }
    if([number integerValue] >= 1000){
        level = 1000;
        format = @"k";
    }
    result = [number integerValue]/level;

    NSString *kValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@",result,format];

    return kValue;
}

+ (void)initialize {
    origStringFromNumberMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(stringFromNumber:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(origStringFromNumberMethod,
                                   class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(stringFromBigNumber:)));
}

@end
```